# Using g++ on OSX Lion, ld: unknown option: -no_compact_unwind

Tags: c++, g++, osx-lion, ld

I followed the instructions at https://sites.google.com/site/dwhipp/tutorials/mac_compilers for OSX Lion and XCode 4.3 to use g++ on the command line, but when I run it I get this:

```
jeff~/Dropbox/cpp$ g++ hello.cpp 
ld: unknown option: -no_compact_unwind
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the latest version of GCC (4.7) by command line on Mac OS X Lion, I have a better solution.

Install MacPorts (you can download the source code and compile it or download the pkg installer):

http://www.macports.org/install.php

Installed MacPort, open the Terminal and type (you need the root password)

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

for updating the port tree. Then type

```
sudo port install gcc47 +universal
```

This command will install the GCC 4.7 compiler on your Mac (this compilation will take a lot of time, be patient). Now you have your GCC 4.7 compiler accessible by the command line under the name

```
gcc-mp-4.7
```

(use `g++-mp-4.7`for C++ compilation). You have also the new C++11 standard adding the option

```
g++-mp-4.7 -std=c++11
```

Comment: In addition, if you install gcc_select with MacPorts, you can tell OSX to use the MacPort gcc47 instead of the default gcc by doing "sudo port select --set gcc gcc47". Now when you use "gcc" you will be using mp-gcc47 (same goes for g++).

Comment: @Corey XCode will also use gcc 4.7 or this holds only for command line tools?

Comment: I am unsure about XCode, I use Vim and makefiles-- haven't crossed that bridge yet, sorry!