# static link boost with g++ on MacOS

Tags: c++, boost, static, g++, static-linking

I'm building a project in C++ using the FLTK toolkit and have included boost libraries for serialisation and would like to statically link to them as I cannot guarantee the existence of the boost libraries on other machines.

I re-ran the install commands from the boost download like so:

```
sudo ./b2 link=static
sudo ./b2 install link=static
```

and am then compiling my project like so

```
g++ `fltk-config --use-forms --use-gl --use-images --ldflags --cxxflags` xxxx.cpp  -L/opt/local/lib/ -Wl, -Bstatic -lboost_iostreams -lboost_serialization -Wl, -Bdynamic -o program_name
```

but get a failure and just this as an output

```
ld: file not found: 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not really sure what to do here, does anyone have any guidance?

Comment: Add -v (or --v) to command line to get more info. Are your boot libraries in /opt/local/lib? Not sure, why are command line arguments in grave accents?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in `-Wl, -Bstatic`. Remove that space, e.g. `-Wl,-Bstatic`.

Same applies to `-Wl, -Bdynamic`.

Comment: Good point, but still not working. Have followed the advice here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022543/using-g-on-osx-lion-ld-unknown-option-no-compact-unwind and installed all things I can think of through macports and am now compiling with this command
    "g++-mp-4.7 `fltk-config --use-forms --use-gl --use-images --ldflags --cxxflags` xxxx.cpp `fltk-config --ldflags` -L/opt/local/lib/ -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_iostreams -lboost_serialization -Wl,-Bdynamic -o program_name"

 but it still returns the following error: ld: unknown option: -Bstatic
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status